# Replace string by regex for tftp

Tags: regex, tftp

I want to use `tftp-hpa` file-remapping feature (see [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/tftpd.8.html#contenttoc5)). It uses regex, but it doesn't have much functionality. What I want is when the client send a request for `foo`, the server send `client_IP/foo`. For the moment I have this rule :

```
r foo \i/foo
```

But as you can guess, it works only for `foo`, whereas I want it to work whatever is the request. I've tried this :

```
r /.*/ \i//.*/
```

But it doesn't work. As the documentation and the examples aren't much, I don't know what to try, so maybe you can have some suggestions. (So yeah, I know it's not really a programing question, but as programmers you know regex and maybe you'll have the good answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a replacement pattern: As stated in the doc, `\0` stands for the "entire string matched by the regex". So try:

```
r .* \i/\0
```

Comment: Nop. But `r foo \i/\0` works (only for `foo`, of course). So it's the `/.*/` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the matched string into the replacement. parantheses mark a positional match, starting with 1:

```
r /(.*)/ \i\/\1/
```

should do the trick (unverified)

Comment: Nop, doesn't work.
Note that TFTP file-remapping are so simple, I'm not even sure what I ask is possible.

Comment: Looks like parenthesis need to be escaped... From the doc: `The strings matched by each  of  the  first  nine  parenthesized subexpressions, \( ... \), of the regex pattern.`